# Library/Framework for Generalized Sequential Pattern Discovery?

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining

I have a CSV file of the following format:

```
session_id,time,item
```

where the possible amount of items is huge.

Which framework/library fits best for that problem (Generalized Sequential Pattern Discovery)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found a reasonable, easy-to-use, Java-based framework which deals with GSP and Sequential Pattern Mining Algorithms:

http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=algorithms.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can't fit the items in memory, so if I understand you correctly, you're looking for a solution which allows you to "process" large amounts of training data. A good solution for that is [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has exectly this algorithm, but it is not very scalable. Convert your data to Instances and you can appply weka to [discover sequence](http://weka.wikispaces.com/GeneralizedSequentialPatterns#Class).  I found it very useful to detecting sequence of words as text features. Also. I've patched it to use lucene and it is now twice as fast and scalable, so it is good start.